# Restore sql database from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, restore

I already check other issue and other answers but it does not solve my problem.

This is a query and This can run on SQL Management Studio

```
USE master Alter DATABASE SATS_Test Set Single_User With Rollback Immediate
 Restore Database SATS_Test From Disk =N'C:\Users\MyPath\05052020t_test.bak' 
 Alter Database SATS_Test Set Multi_User
```

Here is c# code=> the above query is output from `query`

```
string connetionString = null;
                SqlConnection connection;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

                connetionString = "Data Source="+DataAccessHelper.ServerName+";Initial Catalog=master;User ID="+DataAccessHelper.UserID+";Password="+DataAccessHelper.Password;
                connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


                string restorefilepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBBackupPath"].ToString();
                restorefilepath = Path.Combine(restorefilepath, filename);

                string query = @"USE master Alter DATABASE " + DataAccessHelper.DatabaseName + @" Set Single_User With Rollback Immediate" + Environment.NewLine + " Restore Database " + DataAccessHelper.DatabaseName + @" From Disk =N'" + restorefilepath + "' " + Environment.NewLine + " Alter Database " + DataAccessHelper.DatabaseName + " Set Multi_User";

                int result = 0;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

The problem is this result from `ExecuteNonQuery` always returns -1.  What I was wrong?

One thing is, the Current application is using this restore database so my be this database has a connection while restoring the database. Its problem?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The issue is due to returns in the Command Text.  Usually the FROM is at a beginning of a new line.  Also make sure you have spaces in the right locations.

Comment: You should call `connection.Dispose()` immediately after the code has finished using it - the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement is a good way to make it do that for you.

Comment: @jdweng, It looks correct and has the correct space. but it does not restore the DB.

Comment: I suspect it is a credential issue.  Is the server local or on a remote machine?  I think windows firewall is rejecting the username and password in the connection string when connecting to a remote machine.

Comment: @jdweng, Its local server, and I use sa account to restore. Sql connection also can open.

Comment: check the server log files and see if there any indication of access violations.

Answer (score 0):

If no exception occurred, the restore completed successfully. The return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is the rowcounts returned by the batch, or -1 if no rowcounts are returned. `RESTORE` does not return rowcounts.

This restore script forcibly terminates existing connections to the database for the duration of the operation so current app connections will be affected. Depending on how errors are handled (e.g. retries), this can impact application functionality.

Comment: Thank. It's just return - 1 and not restore the database. I also think this restore will effect to current app connection. but I don't know how to achieve this one.

Comment: @Loran, I ran the code snippet in your question (with a hard-coded values for server, database name and file) and the database successfully restored. How do you know the database was not restored? You should see related messages in the SQL Server errorlog. The app connection used to restore the database is in the master db context and will not be affected but all connections using the db will be killed due to the `SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` specification.

Comment: After I several checks, I saw it was restored the database, but some data are missing.If I restore the database from this query,it was restored but `empid` like '001' changes to '1' means 0 upfront value are missing 0 value. but if I restore from the management studio, it's ok. I did the same backup file.

Comment: A restored database is exactly like the original from the backup. But be aware a backup file can contain multiple backups. In that case, the first (oldest) is restored by default unless one specifies the `FILE=` option to indicate the desired backup within the file. Execute `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='C:\SqlBackupFiles\YourBackupFile.bak';` to list the backups in the file.